# ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext - Java + Eclipse + Spark

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Im starting now with Spark. Im trying some example projects and now im working with a project to read from a csv.
The problem comes when i run the app. The console of eclipse tells me the following error:

```
18/09/19 05:00:48 ERROR MetricsSystem: Sink class org.apache.spark.metrics.sink.MetricsServlet cannot be instantiated
18/09/19 05:00:48 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem$$anonfun$registerSinks$1.apply(MetricsSystem.scala:200)
    at org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem$$anonfun$registerSinks$1.apply(MetricsSystem.scala:194)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:99)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:99)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:230)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:40)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem.registerSinks(MetricsSystem.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem.start(MetricsSystem.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:522)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2313)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$6.apply(SparkSession.scala:909)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$6.apply(SparkSession.scala:901)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:901)
    at com.mycsv.app.CSVFileAnalysisInSparkSQL.main(CSVFileAnalysisInSparkSQL.java:28)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat$Value.empty()Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonFormat$Value;
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.cfg.MapperConfig.<clinit>(MapperConfig.java:50)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.<init>(ObjectMapper.java:543)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.<init>(ObjectMapper.java:460)
    at org.apache.spark.metrics.sink.MetricsServlet.<init>(MetricsServlet.scala:48)
    ... 20 more
```

My project code is the following:

```
final SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().appName("Spark CSV").master("local[5]").getOrCreate();
```

What could be the problem with the SparkContext?
Thank you and regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is coming due to missing or incorrect jackson-annotations dependency.Confirm if you are using the correct version in your project build.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow. Unfortuantely this hardly qualifies as an answer. It should have been a https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment . Try improving your answer or delete it, please.

Comment: I have edited my answer with more details .I cant add a comment as I dont have that privilege yet.

Comment: Kuldip, thank you! i revised my pom, and was a problem there. Now my project works. Thank you again and regards.